# How to pass date format at run time spring mvc joda

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jodatime

Based on a property set at environment level

```
store.date.format=DD/MM/YY (or)
store.date.format=MM/DD/YY
```

How can I bind String entered in the screen to joda LocalDate

```
@DateTimeFormat("dd/mm/yy")
private LocalDate birthDate;
```

I want birthDate to accept both dd/mm/yy and mm/dd/yy formats based on store setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a property in the pattern attribute value.

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "${store.date.format}")
private LocalDate birthDate;
```